# How do I find $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0} \frac{e^{5x}-1}{x}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

I have tried several ways to find the limit and reviewed my textbooks but I'm stumped. Plotting it on to Desmos reveals that it's 5 but I don't know how to find the answer algebraically.
$$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{e^{5x}-1}{x}$$

Comment: Are you familiar with L'Hopitals rule? The application of this quickly shows that the result is 5.

Comment: @OliD first time i've heard of it, but i will look into it, thanks!

Comment: Alternatively if you expand the exponential term as a Taylor series you might see why!

Comment: Use the definition of derivative.

Comment: There are multiple ways to solve it like using L'Hopital's rule or using Talylor series expansion for $e^{5x}$ , L'Hoptial probably the easiest way try it and see if you get the correct solution or not

Comment: Do you know what a derivative is? If so then this is simple, but I suspect you may be building up to derivatives at the moment.

Comment: Let $f(x)=e^{5x}$. What is $f'(0)$? And what is the _definition_ of $f'(0)$???

Comment: Robert's comment shows that we do not even need L'Hospital or Taylor here, the definition of the derivate of $e^{5x}$ at $x_0=0$ is enough.

Answer (score 1):

An idea:

$$x^5-y^5=(x-y)(x^4+x^3y+x^2y^2+xy^3+y^4)\implies$$

$$ e^{5x}-1=(e^x-1)(e^{4x}+e^{3x}+e^{2x}+e^x+1)$$

and now use the basic limit

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x-1}x=1$$

and thus you don't need to use L'Hospital rule.

Comment: If the ”basic limit” $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x-1}x=1$ is known then $\frac{e^{5x}-1}{x} = 5 \cdot \frac{e^{5x}-1}{5x} \to 5$ follows immediately, without the need for polynomial division.

Comment: If you know that "basic limit" it's just a matter of change of variable $t = 5 x$.

Comment: @MartinR Only if you already know that $$\lim_{x\to x_0} \frac{e^{f(x)}-1}{f(x)}=1$$ for any function $\;f\;$ such that $\;f(x)\xrightarrow[x\to x_o]{}0\;$ . I am trying to use the minimal ammount of stuff here. Same thing with calculating limits by means of variable changes... And the limit I called "basic" is usually given as such in elementary theory of limits, so it is up to the OP to choose what he can use.